# Why is TextView textColor automatically adjusted to the background color tone

Tags: android, colors, textview, android-color

I recently started to learn Android development. Made a very simple XML layout with just a `LinearLayout` containing some `ImageViews` and `TextViews`. The theme I use in my *styles.xml* is

> Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar

For the TextViews I did not set a textColor yet, but on my phone the text colors are adjusted automatically and match the respective background colors (only darker for more contrast). I love this effect but I do not have any idea where it comes from.

This is one of the TextViews:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>        
<TextView
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_weight="2"
    android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
    android:textSize="22sp"
    android:textStyle="bold"
    android:text="Enjoy your view!" />
```

And this is the result (automatic textColors highlighted in red selection):

[image]

**Which attribute/setting/class or other built-in feature is responsible for that? Does it depend on the phone? Or the theme? Or ...?**

Comment: The default text color for the `Theme.AppCompat.Light` themes is slightly translucent, so that's why it looks like it adjusts for each different background color. (If that's what you mean.)

Comment: Oh my.. really ..  Now I am slightly embarrassed. YES this is what I wanted to know. I just had not idea where to look for a reason - the colors seemed so perfectly adjusted. :-D So it is black/white with a transparency that's why. Huh, maybe you want write to answer so I can accept it as the correct one? Maybe one day there will be someone else who is as confused as I was ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The default text color for the `Theme.AppCompat.Light` themes is slightly translucent, so that's why it looks like it adjusts for each different background color.

We can have a look through the source to determine the actual values, starting with your chosen theme, which is defined in appcompat's [`themes.xml`](https://chromium.googlesource.com/android_tools/+/master/sdk/extras/android/support/v7/appcompat/res/values/themes.xml):

```
<style name="Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar">
    <item name="windowActionBar">false</item>
    <item name="windowNoTitle">true</item>
</style>
```

This inherits from `Theme.AppCompat.Light` in that same XML:

```
<style name="Theme.AppCompat.Light" parent="Base.Theme.AppCompat.Light" />
```

`Base.Theme.AppCompat.Light` is located in [`themes_base.xml`](https://chromium.googlesource.com/android_tools/+/master/sdk/extras/android/support/v7/appcompat/res/values/themes_base.xml):

```
<style name="Base.Theme.AppCompat.Light" parent="Base.V7.Theme.AppCompat.Light">
```

Which leads us to `Base.V7.Theme.AppCompat.Light`, in the same file:

```
<style name="Base.V7.Theme.AppCompat.Light" parent="Platform.AppCompat.Light">
```

And then to `Platform.AppCompat.Light`, where we finally get to a color setting:

```
<style name="Platform.AppCompat.Light" parent="android:Theme.Light">
    ...
    <!-- Text colors -->
    <item name="android:textColorPrimary">@color/abc_primary_text_material_light</item>
    ...
```

[`abc_primary_text_material_light`](https://chromium.googlesource.com/android_tools/+/master/sdk/extras/android/support/v7/appcompat/res/color/abc_primary_text_material_light.xml) is actually a `ColorStateList`, which is defined in XML with a `<selector>` element, and its file is under appcompat's [`res/color/`  directory](https://chromium.googlesource.com/android_tools/+/master/sdk/extras/android/support/v7/appcompat/res/color):

```
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item android:state_enabled="false" android:color="@color/primary_text_disabled_material_light"/>
    <item android:color="@color/primary_text_default_material_light"/>
</selector>
```

At last, we find the default color – `primary_text_default_material_light` – which is a simple color value defined in [`res/values/colors_material.xml`](https://chromium.googlesource.com/android_tools/+/master/sdk/extras/android/support/v7/appcompat/res/values/colors_material.xml):

```
<!-- 87% black -->
<color name="primary_text_default_material_light">#de000000</color>
```

We can see that the alpha channel on the color is not entirely opaque, which explains the observed appearance.

Answer (score 0):

By default `TextView` text color is determined by the `Theme` you applied like your `Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar` but you can change it just add `android:textColor="#FF0000"` in your `TextView` this will change your text color. Here is an example.

```
<TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerInParent="true"
        android:text="TextView"
        android:textSize="36sp"
        android:textColor="#FF0000" />
```

Answer (score 0):

The theme drives your color and behaviors.
Android will apply the default colors to your text based on your base app theme.

You should not allow chance to pick your colors, font sizes and things of that nature. Use your styles to create your generalized needs, sizes, fonts, and colors and apply the style throughout.

Example:

```
 <!--Define custom font type-->
<style name="TextAppearance.Light" parent="android:TextAppearance">
    <item name="fontPath">fonts/Roboto-Light.ttf</item>
</style>

<style name="TextAppearance.Medium" parent="android:TextAppearance">
    <item name="fontPath">fonts/Roboto-Medium.ttf</item>
</style>

<style name="TextAppearance.Regular" parent="android:TextAppearance">
    <item name="fontPath">fonts/Roboto-Regular.ttf</item>
</style>

<!--TextView font type "Roboto-Light" style-->
<style name="MyAppTheme.TextView.Light">
    <item name="android:textAppearance">@style/TextAppearance.Light</item>
</style>

<style name="MyAppTheme.TextView.Light.Small">
    <item name="android:textSize">@dimen/text_size_small</item>
</style>

<style name="MyAppTheme.TextView.Light.Medium">
    <item name="android:textSize">@dimen/text_size_medium</item>
</style>

<style name="MyAppTheme.TextView.Light.Large">
    <item name="android:textSize">@dimen/text_size_large</item>
</style>

<style name="MyAppTheme.TextView.Light.14sp">
    <item name="android:textSize">@dimen/text_size_14</item>
</style>

   <style name="MyAppTheme.TextView.Light.12sp">
    <item name="android:textSize">@dimen/text_size_14</item>
</style>

<!--TextView font type "Roboto-Medium" style-->
<style name="MyAppTheme.TextView.Medium">
    <item name="android:textAppearance">@style/TextAppearance.Medium</item>
</style>

<style name="MyAppTheme.TextView.Medium.Small">
    <item name="android:textSize">@dimen/text_size_small</item>
</style>

<style name="MyAppTheme.TextView.Medium.Medium">
    <item name="android:textSize">@dimen/text_size_medium</item>
</style>

<style name="MyAppTheme.TextView.Medium.Large">
    <item name="android:textSize">@dimen/text_size_large</item>
</style>

<!--TextView font type "Roboto-Regular" style-->
<style name="MyAppTheme.TextView.Regular">
    <item name="android:textAppearance">@style/TextAppearance.Regular</item>
</style>

<style name="MyAppTheme.TextView.Regular.Small">
    <item name="android:textSize">@dimen/text_size_small</item>
</style>

<style name="MyAppTheme.TextView.Regular.Medium">
    <item name="android:textSize">@dimen/text_size_medium</item>
</style>

<style name="MyAppTheme.TextView.Regular.Large">
    <item name="android:textSize">@dimen/text_size_large</item>
</style>

<style name="MyAppTheme.TextView.Regular.13sp">
    <item name="android:textSize">@dimen/text_size_13</item>
</style>
```

//General TextView Theme

```
 <!--TextView text color and single line true-->
<style name="MyAppTheme.TextView">
    <item name="android:singleLine">true</item>
    <item name="android:textColor">@android:color/white</item>
</style>
```

//now make the ones that will differ from your normal text theme from there.
Then all textviews will obey the above one, unless you change the style in the layout file itself with the style="@styles/MyAppTheme.SomeOtherTextStyle"

example:

```
<TextView
                android:id="@+id/txtLastSavedLabel"
                style="@style/MyAppTheme.TextView.Light.Small"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_centerVertical="true"
                android:text="@string/configuration_list_item_last_saved" />
```